# Problem with DropDownListFor SelectedItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

This has totally puzzled me.

Here's my View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ScoreDescription, 
                               Model.RatingOptions, 
                               "--", 
                               new { @id = clientId })
```

And the model:

```
public decimal? Score { get; set; }
public SelectList RatingOptions
{ 
    get
    {
        var options = new List<SelectListItem>();

        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            options.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Selected = Score.HasValue && Score.Value == Convert.ToDecimal(i),
                Text = ((decimal)i).ToRatingDescription(ScoreFactorType),
                Value = i.ToString()
            });
        }

        var selectList = new SelectList(options, "Value", "Text");
            // At this point, "options" has an item with "Selected" to true.
            // Also, the underlying "MultiSelectList" also has it.
            // Yet selectList.SelectedValue is null. WTF?
        return selectList;
    }
}
```

As the comments suggest, i can't get the selected value to happen.

Is it something to do with the fact i'm using a nullable `decimal` ? After that loop, `options` is correct in that it has exactly 1 item with select to true, so it seems i'm doing the right thing.

Now, if i use a *different* `SelectList` overload:

```
var selectedValue = Score.HasValue ? Score.Value.ToString("0") : string.Empty;
var selectList = new SelectList(options, "Value", "Text", selectedValue);
```

It works. Why? At first i thought it might be a LINQ-trick (e.g deferred execution), but i tried forcing a `.ToList()` and there is no difference.

It's like setting the `Selected` property as you create the `SelectListItem` has no effect, and you have you set it at the end using the `SelectList` ctor parameter.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of the SelectList class it never actually uses the fact that you are passing a `SelectListItem`. It works with an `IEnumerable`. So the `Selected` property of a `SelectListItem` is not used. Personally I prefer setting the *selected* value of a dropdown by setting the value of the corresponding property that you are binding the ddl to.

Example:

```
public int? Score { get; set; }
public SelectList RatingOptions
{ 
    get
    {
        var options = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(i => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = ((decimal)i).ToRatingDescription(ScoreFactorType),
            Value = ((decimal)i).ToString()
        });
        return new SelectList(options, "Value", "Text");
    }
}
```

and then in the controller action simply set the `Score` property to the necessary value and in the view use this Score property to bind to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Score, 
    Model.RatingOptions, 
    "--", 
    new { @id = clientId }
)
```

Comment: Right, so basically my last sentence is correct - the Selected property of SelectListItem is pointless in this scenario. Cheers.