# DropDownListFor does not select correct value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I know there are already some threads about this topic and I followed some of them with no success.

**The problem:**
I have a DropDownListFor that has a list of countries. When I choose a country and submit the form, it is saved correctly in database but when I load the form again to edit it, it always shows the first item.
I have other dropdowns implemented in a similar way and they are working correctly.

**What I have tried**

1. I have changed the name of properties because I read that when using ViewBag to pass the list to fill the dropdown, it can fail to select the correct value. NO success.
2. I have replace viewbag for a property in the ViewModel. No success.

**The Code**

View:

```
<div class="input-group col-md-5">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.CountryCode, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Alpha2Code", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var userViewModel = await _userLogicLayer.GetUserViewModelAsync(MySession.UserId);
userViewModel.Countries = LocaleLogicLayer.Countries;
return View(userViewModel);
```

LocaleLogicLayer:

```
public static class LocaleLogicLayer
{

    public static List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    static LocaleLogicLayer()
    {
        Countries = new List<Country>
        {
            new Country() {Alpha2Code = "PT", Name = "Portugal"},
            new Country() {Alpha2Code = "BR", Name = "Brasil"},
            new Country() {Alpha2Code = "XX", Name = "Outro"}
        };
    }
}
```

GetUserViewModelAsync

```
public async Task<UserViewModel> GetUserViewModelAsync(string userId)
        {
            var userProfile = await _userProfileRepository.GetAsync(userId);
            var userViewModel = new UserViewModel();

            if (userProfile != null)
            {
                userViewModel.Id = userProfile.Id;
                userViewModel.LinkedInProfile = userProfile.LinkedInProfile;
                userViewModel.Nif = userProfile.Nif;
                userViewModel.Bi = userProfile.Bi;
                userViewModel.Picture = userProfile.Picture;
                userViewModel.CountryCode = userProfile.CountryCode;

            }

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userViewModel.Id) ? null : userViewModel;
    }
```

I appreciate you help. It must be a very basic error but I'm not finding it.
Thank you very much.

**Edit(new approach)**

[image: CountriesX has now a SelectList]

New DropDownlList

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, (SelectList)ViewBag.CountriesX, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

(and still not working, so frustrating)

Comment: What's the value of `userViewModel.CountryCode` in the controller code?

Comment: If I select Brasil is "BR", Portugal "PT" and "XX" in the remaining case

Comment: Yes, it has. It saves correctly to database and also reads the correct value. the problem is that the view just ignores it.

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the code of `GetUserViewModelAsync` method?

Comment: I added the method you requested. Thks for trying to help me

Comment: put a breakpoint before you return the viewmodel, then double check the `userViewModel.CountryCode` value is in your select list.

Comment: I had. It shows the correct value, always :(

Comment: Can you post the full view?  Are you doing anything else that might affect the model?

Comment: By the way, you can set a breakpoint in your view.  If you set your cursor on the `model.CountryCode` just to the right of the `=>` and hit F9 then the debugger will break when it renders that part of the view, and you can check the contents of model.CountryCode and ViewBag.Countries

Comment: I already did. The picture (about debug value) in my question is in the controller but it has the same value in the view

Comment: @sergiommaria - and did you check the values of Countries as well in the View?  Do you, by any chance have any JavaScript that might be resetting the value?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of `Html.DropDownListFor` is a lambda expression, so you should pass `model => model.CountryCode` instead of `model => Model.CountryCode` (notice the big and small M difference). I'd also suggest passing an instance of `List<SelectListItem>` as the second argument of `Html.DropDownListFor` method and setting it inside the constructor of `UserViewModel`.

Change your model class code to below, what you need to do is changing the type of `Countries` property to `List<SelectListItem>` and add a constructor method:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class UserViewModel
{
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        this.Countries = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Portugal", Value = "PT" }
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Brasil", Value = "BR" }
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Outro", Value = "XX" }
        };
    }

    public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }

    .... // other existing properties
}
```

then your controller code should be like below

```
var userViewModel = await _userLogicLayer.GetUserViewModelAsync(MySession.UserId);
return View(userViewModel);
```

and your view code

```
<div class="input-group col-md-5">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryCode, Model.Countries, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try @ekad's answer first, since that could very well be the issue and it's something you'll need to correct either way. However, if it's still not working, then try not creating your own `SelectList`. `SelectList` takes, as a parameter to its constructor, a selected value, which you are not passing in, meaning nothing will be selected initially. If @ekad's answer is enough to fix your problem, then that means Razor is helpfully going behind you and setting the selected value.

Either way, though, it's far better to pass an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to `Html.DropDownListFor`, which you could create via:

```
Model.Countries.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Alpha2Code, Text = m.Name })
```

If you utilize a view model, it's better to move this into your action code and actually set a property on your view model to that. Then you can just do something like:

```
Html.DropDownListForm(m => m.CountryCode, Model.CountryChoices)
```

Much less code and logic in your view, which is always a good thing.

Comment: I have tried your suggestions and still does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You not select a value to drop down selected it!
Try this to your html:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryCode,null,null)
```

and your code is:

```
var userViewModel = await _userLogicLayer.GetUserViewModelAsync(MySession.UserId);
ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(LocaleLogicLayer.Countries,"Alpha2Code","Name",userViewModel.CountryCode);
return View(userViewModel);
```

Comment: I have updated my code (and question) with last suggestions. Still same result... :(

Answer (score 0):

After some more hours researching, I finally found the solution to my problem:
What I didn't understand was why similar code was working for other fields and not this one. After I bound it to another property it worked perfectly. So, I found I have a static property on my base Controller class assigned this way:

```
ApplicationController.Locale.CountryCode = countryCode;
```

- this value comes from the Url. So, CountryCode is a static field of a static class "Locale" assigned on my base controller class and I never reference it in my view.

**Conclusion:** I got it well but can anyone explain me WHY does this happen? For me, it makes no sense.

Note: It looks like we don't need to pass the selectedListItem in the selectedList. Anyway it should be good for code coherence and does not hurt.
[Problem with DropDownListFor SelectedItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892416/problem-with-dropdownlistfor-selecteditem)

All posts were valuable and I improved my final solution based on that, so thanks to all of you for your time and insights.